# Why Ubuntu auto remove software and some software I cannot open it but before I still can open it and HOW TO FIX THESE PROBLEM?

Tags: 20.04, login

Hi I will describe the problem I have with you (I use Ubuntu version 20.04.1 LTS):

**-** First,while i using i feel Ubuntu is running slowly so I restarted it, then the screen is stuck in displaying a message that is `/dev/sda9: clean,231388/915712 file,3080564/3662080 blocks`.

**-** I went inside Ubuntu by type `ctrl+alt+f1` to it appear login display then login with my account and type command `sudo systemctl enable gdm.service --now` to into Ubuntu interface

**-** When into Ubuntu interface I see I has lost some software like google chrome,SimpleScreenRecorder I installed before ,firefox default software also auto removed . I cannot open image jpg,png type but before i still can open it ,rar,zip is the same . Another thing is that I cannot open some software like Ubuntu Center, netbeans,opera,....

**-** Anyone tell me what are those errors? And how to fix them ?

Comment: your filesystem might be corrupted when you force-restarted the system

Comment: if it's slow, you should do Alt+PrtScn+REISUB in turn

Comment: FYI:  @NinePlusTenEqualsTwentyOne's comment is a suggestion to use a SysRq key (alt+SysRq, the SysRq key is usually found on the PrtScr key however check on your own keyboard where it's located; it can be elsewhere too, and require Fn on some devices).  If you're unsure how to safely shutdown, a online search via phone for "magic sysrq" will find the wikipedia article on it which is a good reminder of what the commands are, it'll provide explanation for REISUB.  If you don't cleanly shutdown, you should `fsck` or file-system check first in my opinion.

Comment: Packages should only get removed automatically if you caused a requirement to be removed (ie. next autoclean/autoremove will remove clean up prior packages & anything impacted by the removal of packages removed in prior commands).  This is caused by users with `sudo` privileges removing packages that are required (*depends* rules) by other packages, the fault being a prior command that should not have been executed. Check your `apt` logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log` for date & time of the `sudo` command that caused the effect..